# Количество отображаемых элементов в направлении в слайдере swiper

Tags: html, css, swiper, swiper.js

Нужно было сделать слайдер из 3 слайдов, чтобы один заменял другой, то есть бесконечный. Сделал я это через библиотеку swiper.  Проблема заключается в следующем, когда я вращаю слайдер влево, то есть как бы обратно, то проблем не возникает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я вращаю слайдер вправо, то есть по направлению, весь слайдер смещается влево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобным.